# Redux state fails to update on error cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, redux

So I'm new to React & I created a Registration page.

The problem is if I give an invalid input, then MongoDB throws an Error.
It seems to work well in pages like `Login` and `UserProfile`, and not in `UserRegistration`

If there is a blank field, the page redirects to the homepage showing no error.
Status code is given in console, but the error is not being thrown.

The state is supposed to update itself to have key-value pair of error but it updates to

```
userInfo: 'error message'
```

Reducer:

```
export const userRegisterReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case USER_REGISTER_REQUEST:
          return { loading: true }
        case USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS:
          return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload }
        case USER_REGISTER_FAIL:
          return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
        case USER_LOGOUT:
          return {}
        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

Action Creator:

```
export const register = (name, email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_REQUEST,
    })

    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }

    const { data } = await axios.post(
      '/api/users',
      { name, email, password },
      config
    )

    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })

    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: data,
    })

    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_REGISTER_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

State:

```
userLogin: {
     loading: false,
     message(pin):"User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is 
     required., password: Path `password` is required."
     stack(pin):"ValidationError: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required. at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2693:32) at C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2513:17 at C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1241:9 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)"
}

userRegister: {
     loading: false,
     message(pin):"User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is 
     required., password: Path `password` is required."
     stack(pin):"ValidationError: User validation failed: name: Path `name` is required., email: Path `email` is required., password: Path `password` is required. at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2693:32) at C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2513:17 at C:\Users\Fayaz B\Desktop\Fayaz\Dev\Portfolio\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:1241:9 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)"
}
```

MongoDB register controller:

```
const registerUser = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body

  const userExists = await User.findOne({ email })

  if (userExists) {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('User already exists')
  }

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
  })

  if (user) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: user._id,
      name: user.name,
      email: user.email,
      isAdmin: user.isAdmin,
      token: generateToken(user._id),
    })
  } else {
    res.status(400)
    throw new Error('Invalid user data')
  }
})
```

Comment: `axios` request might return an error response, but it won't throw an error, while your code only handles thrown exceptions. you need to check status of the response and if it's not 200 dispatch `USER_REGISTER_FAIL`

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! It seems a good work around. My doubt is, for requests like userLogin, the axios get request is made and throws the error and shows up as error.message rather than storing it to res.data in this case, why is that not working here ? Is there anything that I do wrong here